# bash selective filename expansion to pass to daemon

Tags: bash, daemon, expansion

I want to define a function or alias that starts a process as a daemon but that also can still grok filenames passed to it.  think:

```
function emacs() {
    daemon /usr/bin/emacs $*
}
```

this should work for

```
emacs localfile.txt /tmp/anotherfile.txt
```

I probably need a function that changes localfile.txt to $PWD/localfile.txt , but not /tmp/anotherfile.txt.  is there a bash-elegant way to do this?  advice appreciated.  if not, I am thinking of writing this in perl.

/iaw

Comment: Mind to tell us what executable file you really intend to run your function to? Because I don't see how emacs could really work in the background.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you weren't changing the arguments, you'd want to use `"$@"`, not `$*`.  Otherwise spaces will cause the argument list to be re-split.

But sure.  Try this.

```
function emacs() {
  local args=() a
  for a in "$@"; do 
    case "$a" in [/-]*) args+=("$a");;  # pass options and absolute filenames as-is
                     *) args+=("$PWD/$a");; # absolutify anything else
    esac
  done
  daemon "$(type -P emacs)" "${args[@]}"
}
```

This still breaks for any option arguments that aren't files, but it's a start.

However, that assumes that `emacs` works as a daemon, which it probably doesn't due to the lack of a controlling terminal.  So I'm guessing the actual application is not a text editor.. or is one that maintains its own window, or something.

Comment: thank you.  actually, emacs nicely works as an X gnome app.  I want to make very sure that I don't get any logs or errors sent to the initiating terminal, and that I can terminate the initiating terminal.  I know nohup and &> could do the job, but daemon seems great for this.

Answer (score 1):

`realpath <filename>` does exactly what you want.
Give it a bare filename, a relative path, an absolute path - doesn't matter, it will return the absolute path.

Comment: poifect.  function emacs() { daemon /usr/bin/emacs \`realpath $*\` }

Comment: @user1539216 It occurs to me to teach you to fish, rather than just give you a fish. I didn't actually know about `realpath` either when I first saw your question. I just ran `apropos path` to get a list of man[ual] pages for functions that involve paths, and then ran `man <function_name>` on the ones that looked likely, until I found what I wanted. (If you're new to man pages, it's `q` to quit the page.)